# Mobile-Architecture: Based on Xamarin: How to create a data-centric mobile app? (e.g. with Xamarin.Forms/REST)?

Tags: c#, sql, forms, rest, xamarin

I've a rather large and complex MSSQL-Database model and want to display/edit these data from mobile apps (Android/iOS at least, best Windows Phone, too) built on top of Xamarin.

What's the best approach for this?

Some findings:
Ok, I was thinking about exposing the Database as REST-Service, using e.g. a tool like
dreamfactory.com to be able to switch later to another backend-database without changing a lot.
On the Xamarin-Client-Side there is a Simple REST-Client available:
http://components.xamarin.com/view/restsharp
And for creating the Cross-Platform-Forms there is now Xamarin.Forms.

=> But where can I add "custom server side logic"? OK, I could do this in another server-side C# application which is filling/processing the database.

=> But isn't there a better way to "wire" directly the REST-Calls with the Forms-Elements? Type of generating some basic code and then just edit it to adapt to conrete needs?

Or are there even other frameworks available which work more efficiently in such a situation? It can not be a "cloud-only" framework, e.g. something like wakanda.org (where I can deploy the server part for free on my own -virtual- windows server).

PS: I need native code in Xamarin on the mobile app-side, I can't use just HTML/jQuery.Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is ServiceStack. It would be easy to pull down the SQL Server database structure into POCO's using T4 templates. ServiceStack.OrmLite will work on iOS and Android but unfortunately not with WP8. ServiceStack also has its own web service framework with fast JSON serializers and ProtoBuffer plugins. This would be one option to use to maximize code share. The ServiceStack version 4 is on commercial license, V3 is BSD licensed.

With minor code tweaks you could use SQLite.Net on the mobile side so you can include WP8 as well.